# Need explanation to Array.prototype.reduce() syntax

Tags: javascript

I am using the Array.prototype.reduce() function on one of my arrays that contains multiple entries of the same value to produce a new array with just one instance of each value (unique values). I am using the function correctly and it's producing the correct result. Despite that, there is a piece to this code that I don't understand. All I want to ask is if someone can explain to me how this piece of code is working. I want to understand this to further my knowledge of Javascript. Here is the entire code:

```
var uniqueNames = names.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
  if(accumulator.indexOf(currentValue) === -1) {
    accumulator.push(currentValue);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

I understand everything that is going on here besides the very last part of the code. The part I'm referring to is

```
}, []);
```

What is happening right here? I know the square brackets denote an array and I'm guessing this piece of code has something to do with turning the accumulator into an array? I'm assuming if this piece of code wasn't there, 'accumulator' would be a value rather than an array. But I can't fully grasp what is going on. I would like to be able to explain this to myself in my own words. Can someone help me understand exactly what the code is doing here?

Comment: The second argument is the initial value of the accumulator. Did you have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: It's well described in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters (see `accumulator` and `initialValue`)

Comment: I appreciate the clarification. I have looked at the MDN documentation. That is actually where I got the block of code from. I just didn't think to go back and read the Syntax section. I now see that I should take more time to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Syntax), Array.reduce() takes as an optional argument the initial value to set the accumulator. This means that your accumulator variable is initialised to an emtpy array before the first iteration.

Comment: Thank you sir. I understand now what is happening. Do you happen to know why the code block shows a comma between the left bracket and the initialValue? `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])`

Comment: Sure, this is the syntax that MDN uses to indicate an optional parameter in a function definition.